# a PEP 8 "import formatting" plugin for VIM

Tags: python, vim, plugins, format, pep

I am looking for a plugin which would help me format the order of imports in my python file following given guidelines:
Imports should be grouped in the following order:

1    Standard library imports.

2    Related third party imports.

3    Local application/library specific imports.

Please recommend something:)

Comment: btw autopep8 does not help or I am missing something in the docs

Comment: Requests for software are not considered [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: These is a pre-commit hook to achieve this.
https://github.com/FalconSocial/pre-commit-python-sorter

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One software that sorts imports according to the rules you provided (PEP8) is [`isort`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort), and it also has `vim` plugins. Check the list of available plugins: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/wiki/isort-Plugins.